# VBA "This Command is not Available because no document is open"

Tags: vba, save

Being new to the VBA language, I have researched this simple task for hours and I am having nothing work.  I am getting the error back  "This Command is not Available because no document is open", and there is a word document with writing coming right up.  What is going on here?  Thanks for your help.

```
Sub excel_to_word()
Dim wapp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document

Set wapp = CreateObject("word.application")
wapp.Visible = True


Set wdoc = wapp.Documents.Add

wdoc.Content.InsertAfter Range("B5")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))


'CreateObject("Word.Application").ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\USERS\JOSEPH\DESKTOP\"
 Dim NEWPATH As String
 NEWPATH = "C:\USERS\JOSEPH\DESKTOP"


   CreateObject("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="joseph.docx",       FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, LockComments:=False, Password:="", addtorecentfiles:=False, savenativepictureformat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, saveasaoceletter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=14



End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CreateObject("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:="joseph.docx" 'etc
```

should be

```
wdoc.SaveAs2 Filename:="joseph.docx" 'etc
```

When you call `CreateObject` the second time you're creating a whole new instance of Word (and that second instance doesn't have any document open in it). .